# three.js: How can I target object's position to another (grouped) object, while allowing rotation to follow AR camera?

Tags: javascript, three.js, augmented-reality, tracking, mindar

I'm using an augmented reality library that does some fancy image tracking stuff. After learning a whole lot about this project, I'm now beyond my current ability and could use some help. For our purposes, the library creates an (empty) anchor point at the center of an IRL image target in-camera. Then moves the virtual world around the IRL camera.

My goal is to drive `plane.rotation` to always face the camera, while keeping `plane.position` locked to the anchor point. Additionally, `plane.rotation` values will be referenced later in development.

```
const THREE = window.MINDAR.IMAGE.THREE;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const start = async() => {
    // initialize MindAR 
    const mindarThree = new window.MINDAR.IMAGE.MindARThree({
      container: document.body,
      imageTargetSrc: '../../assets/targets/testQR.mind',
    });
    const {renderer, scene, camera} = mindarThree;

    // create AR object
    const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1.25);
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ffff, transparent: true, opacity: 0.5});
    const plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    // create anchor
    const anchor = mindarThree.addAnchor(0);
     anchor.group.add(plane);

    // start AR
    await mindarThree.start();
    renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    });
  }
  start();
});
```

Everything I've tried so far went into the solutions already massaged into the (functioning draft) code. I have, however, done some research and found a couple avenues that might or might not work. Just tossing them out to see what might stick or inspire another solution. Skill-wise, I'm still in the beginner category, so any help figuring this out is much appreciated.

- identify plane object by its group index number;
  drive (override lib?) object rotation (x, y, z) to face camera;
- possible solutions from dev:

  1. "You can get those values through the anchor object, e.g. `anchor.group.position`.  Meaning that you can use the current three.js API and get those values but without using it for rendering i.e. don't append the `renderer.domElement` to document."
  2. "You can hack into the [source code of mindar (it's open source)](https://github.com/hiukim/mind-ar-js)."
  3. "Another way might be easier for you to try is to just create another camera yourself. I believe you can have multiple cameras, and just render another layer on top using your new camera."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be as simple as calling [`lookAt`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt) in the animation loop function:

```
// start AR
await mindarThree.start();
renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  plane.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3());
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

This assumes the camera is always located at (0,0,0) (i.e., `new THREE.Vector3()`). This seems to be true from my limited testing. I found it helpful to debug by copy-pasting the [MindAR three.js example](https://hiukim.github.io/mind-ar-js-doc/more-examples/threejs-image) into this [codepen](https://codepen.io/evces/pen/vYrwQXW) and printing some relevant values to the console.

Also note that, internally, [MindAR's three.js module](https://github.com/hiukim/mind-ar-js/blob/master/src/image-target/three.js) seems to directly modify the world matrix of the `anchor.group` object without modifying the position/rotation/scale parameters.

Comment: I was making that way more complicated than it needed to be. Thanks for the help and note about `anchor.group` parameters.